# Face_Recognition issue loading encoding file

Tags: python, opencv, numpy-ndarray, face-recognition

I want to create a .csv file to speed up the loading of the encoding file of my face recognition program using face_recognition on python.

When my algorithm detect a new face, he generate an encoding file using face_recognition and then:

```
                with open('data.csv', 'a') as file:

                writer = csv.writer(file)
                writer.writerow([ID,new_face_reco])
```

I do that to send the code to the .csv file. (ID is a random name I give to the face and new_face_reco is the encoding of the new face)

But I want to reopen it when i relaunch the progam so I have this at the beginning:

```
known_face_encodings_temp = []
known_face_names_temp = []

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as file:
    data = [row for row in csv.reader(file,delimiter=',')]

    known_face_names_temp.append(np.array(data[0][0]))
    essai = np.array(data[0][1].replace('\n',''))
    known_face_encodings_temp.append(essai.tolist())


known_face_encodings=known_face_encodings_temp
known_face_name=known_face_names_temp
```

I have a lot of issue (this is why they are a lot of line in this part) cause my encoding change from the .csv to the reload of it. Here is what I got:

Initial data:

```
array([-8.31770748e-02, ... , -3.41368467e-03])
```

When I try to reload my csv (without me trying to change anything):

```
'[-1.40143648e-01  ... -8.10057670e-02\n  3.77673171e-02  1.40102580e-02  8.14460665e-02  
7.52283633e-02]'
```

What i do when i try to change thing:

```
'[-1.40143648e-01 ...  7.52283633e-02]'
```

I need to have my load data the same as the initial data what can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using CSV files, try using numpy (.npy) files; they're much easier to save and load. I have used them myself in one of my projects that utilizes the face_recognition module and would be happy to help you out.

To save an encoding, you can:

```
np.save(path to save, encoding)
```

To load an encoding, you can:

```
encodingVariable = np.load(path to load)
```